# Struggling with plotting the solution of ODE having step function using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode

I am trying to use MATLAB to solve the ODE involving step function
[image]

Here is my code to solve the above ODE:

```
syms t s Y y(t) Dy(t) u(t) f(t) k
Dy = diff(y,t)
D2y = diff(Dy,t)
f = heaviside(t) + 2*symsum((-1)^k*heaviside(t-k*pi()),k,1,Inf)
eqn = D2y +0.1*Dy + y == f
leqn = laplace(eqn,t,s)
LT_Y=subs (leqn, laplace (y,t,s),Y);
LT_Y=subs (LT_Y, y(0), 0);
LT_Y=subs(LT_Y, subs(diff(y(t), t), t, 0), 0);
Y=solve(LT_Y,Y);
y=ilaplace(Y,s,t)
```

However, the result seems strange and I cannot plot the graph of the solution. Could anyone tell me what should I do to my code so that I can plot the solution? Thank you so much

Comment: Is there a requirement to find a symbolic solution or could you just use `ode45` with `f(t)=sign(sin(t))`?

Comment: Hello, there is no such requirement, I just need to choose interval of n and t which is wide enough to plot the solution so that the transient part of the solution has become negligible and the steady state is clearly shown.

Answer (score 2):

The decay rate of the friction term is `0.1/2=0.05`, so you need about `t=40` for a decay of `0.1`. In a standard plot features down to `1%` of the plot size are visible, which would require a time span of `t=80`, or longer for some visual confirmation of the stabilization of the amplitude at that level.

The right side is about in resonance with the left one, so the steady-state solution will roughly look like `-10*cos(t)` plus higher frequency components.

Just for plotting a numerical solution is sufficient

```
opts=odeset("AbsTol",1e-6,"RelTol",1e-9);
[T,Y] = ode45(@(t,y)[y(2); f(t)-0.1*y(2)-y(1)], [0, 100], [0;0], opts);
plot(T,Y(:,1),T,-13*cos(T));

function z=f(t)
    z = sign(sin(t));
end
```

This gives the plot below, blue for the solution and green for the reference (guessed amplitude)

[image: plot of wave and reference]

---

Computing the Fourier series for the right side, the amplitude of the cosine component of the solution is `40/pi=12.732`.